# In hook_boot jQuery is undefined

Tags: 7, hooks, javascript

I am doing some processing in `hook_boot` since I need that code to run on every page, irrespective of whether or not they are cached.

As a result, jQuery is undefined when I add inline JavaScript to the page.

```
function hook_boot() {
  drupal_add_js("jQuery('document').ready(function() { //do });");
}
```

The idea is that we will potentially load a lightbox on every page after processing in `hook_boot`.

The only way I can see round this is using `variable_set` and then retrieving that in another hook (e.g `hook_node_*`). However, that might not be sufficient since we need it to run on *every* page.

How would you get round this?

Answer (score 1):

If you add the JavaScript in [hook_init](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_init/7), then it will be there the next time the page is served from the cache.

And if the page is served from the cache, then calling [drupal_add_js](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) in [hook_boot](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_init/7) will not add JavaScript to the page, because the page is not assembled from calling the page callback, but is served from the cache.

Use [hook_init](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_init/7) instead of [hook_boot](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_init/7).

Comment: The problem then is that I want to load the JS conditionally, e.g. `if(variable_get('show_js', 0)) drupal_add_js();` which isn't possible given that `hook_init` isn't run on every page.

Comment: Clear the cache when the value of the variable changes.

Answer (score 1):

I would write a menu hook that replies with "yes, run a function" or "no, don't run a function" (eg, your conditional logic's answer) and is called on every page via ajax. You don't have to worry about expiring your caches that way.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have it both ways - if you use the page cache than you lose the ability to deliver a unique response tailored to each visitor.

The answer is usually to serve the same script to all anonymous users, and move the conditional logic into the script itself.  If you are switching based on some user action or input, you can store the user data in a cookie or localstorage.

Comment: How would I serve the same script to all anonymous users?

Comment: You would add the script in hook_init, either unconditionally (for all users), or test using the function user_is_anonymous() if you only want to include it for anonymous users.